# FFMpeg - Issue with slicing QT videos

Tags: qt, ffmpeg

We use ffmpeg in one of our applications to slice videos. While it's working fine for slicing PAL videos, it is not working for QT videos... Here's the command we use:

ffmpeg.exe -i "input.mp4" ss startTime -c copy -to stopTime -y "output.mp4"

Throws an error - "[mp4 @ 0515c240] Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16le in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container"

The input videos are created by a solid state digital video recording system which records videos from following Input channels:
6 channels of videos input (DVI-4No.s, PAL-2No.s)
2 channels of audio input (Left & Right)
2 channels of MIL STD 1553B bus data
2 channels of RS422 data

What could be the issue & how can it be resolved?

Comment: It is discouraged to [crosspost the same question](http://superuser.com/questions/1092259/ffmpeg-unable-to-slice-qt-videos) on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg does not support PCM audio in MP4 container. Output to MOV instead.

Run

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -ss startTime -to stopTime -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero out.mov
```